# Mysql syntax error in this transaction code? Very frustrating

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this code for a small transaction. But MYSQL keeps throwing syntax error.  I wrote the code below in a  .sql file and I run it in mysql using the command 'source filename' but it throws the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1,"A1", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2,"A2", 1000' at line 2
```

Can you find error in my code as shown below?

```
DELIMITER **
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1,"A1", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2,"A2", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (3,"A3", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (4,"A4", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (5,"A5", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (6,"A6", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (7,"A7", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (8,"A8", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (9,"A9", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (10,"A10", 10000,100);
END TRANSACTION;
DELIMITER ;
```

I thought that syntax for INSERT might be wrong but when I run only an insert query, it works.
 I can't find anything wrong in here. I use mysql 5.5.41

Comment: mysql 14.14 ?? looks like you are way into the future..

Comment: Sorry, that enter code here is not a part of my code. It was there by mistake while I was typing it into stack overflow!

Comment: Sure, can you please edit the question with your exact code?. one of us can help you out with the formatting. Also the exact error message would be useful..

Comment: This is the error mysql throws:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1,"A1", 10000,100);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2,"A2", 1000' at line 2

Comment: It is better to be explicit example: `INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1,"A1", 10000,100)` should be `INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (1,"A1", 10000,100)`

Comment: Sorry I mean, version 5.5.41 hahaha! And this is it, the code! It is actually stored in a sql file and I run it in mysql using the command 'source filename'

Comment: It should not make any difference, I tried it anyways. Error remains the same!

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28518402/edit) your question to fix mistakes and add the error message as your question is not understandable as-is.

Comment: Yep it does, I use InnoDB which support transactions!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: But when I add a semicolon there and run it, It does not behave like a transaction. I intentionally mistyped the 6th insert command in my code if transaction works or not. MYSQL throws syntax error as expected but it saves the 5 INSERT queries. Why is that happening? And yes, I use InnoDB storage engine!